# Link to a Url for Css, Js of a Webpage.

Tags: hyperlink

I have a web page content ex: index.html, for css, js.  I want to link this content (i.e.  content of index.html,for css, js)  to some other web page? I have used it some times ago, something like  but could not remember now. Can any one help? 
Thanks.

Comment: something like <base herf="url of the page"> to access all css and js of the url in the href.

Answer (score 0):

Point to an external JavaScript file:

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

Point to an external CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however it is the common way for calling ONE particular css/js, but we can get ALL css/js of a page, by simply calling the url of a page(not particular css/js url instead url of the page), something like <base herf=""> or <meta href"">, I could not remember exactly, we call in head. can help?